# kallsyms initializing process, how s_start works?

Tags: kernel, proc

I am trying to figure out how the kallsyms initializing works.
from kallsyms.c I found this struct

```
static const struct seq_operations kallsyms_op = {
    .start = s_start,
    .next = s_next,
    .stop = s_stop,
    .show = s_show
};
```

so I belive, that the first function that is running on start is s_start.

```
static void *s_start(struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
{
    if (!update_iter(m->private, *pos))
        return NULL;
    return m->private;
}
```

and from here the `update_iter` is called.
until here, all is very clear. 
now I am trying to find how the s_start is initializing the `iter` object so s_show can use it.

The only function that is called in `s_start` is `update_iter` -

```
/* Returns false if pos at or past end of file. */
static int update_iter(struct kallsym_iter *iter, loff_t pos)
{
    /* Module symbols can be accessed randomly. */
    if (pos >= kallsyms_num_syms)
        return update_iter_mod(iter, pos);

    /* If we're not on the desired position, reset to new position. */
    if (pos != iter->pos)
        reset_iter(iter, pos);

    iter->nameoff += get_ksymbol_core(iter);
    iter->pos++;

    return 1;
}
```

and this function really looks like an initializing function. I found this - https://onebitbug.me/2011/03/04/introducing-linux-kernel-symbols/ article explaining how `update_iter_nod` works.

The think that is not clear for me is - why `pos >= kallsyms_num_syms` is true? as logically (at least for me) `pos` is 0 at `s_start`. so update_iter need to pass to `get_ksymbol_core` or `reset_iter` and return 1 -> which will cause returning NULL from `s_start` and I think it's not the way it works.

why the POS is bigger/equal than kallsyms_num_syms?

tried to find any readable documentation of these function but didn't found anything about that line